# Real-time scraping website with Django: stoppable scraping process and loading bar

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, celery

**What I would like to achieve**

I would like to make a website that allows users to scrape information from other websites. My goal is to achieve something as follows:

1. User presses "scrape"
2. When the scraping process begins, Django renders a view with a loading message and a "stop" button
3. If the user presses the "stop" button, or if the scraping process terminates, a view with the scraping results is shown

**Current state**

At the moment, I have a very simple scraping website with a horrible user experience. After the user presses scrape, I render a view similar to the following one:

```py
def scraping_view(request, scraper_args):
    scrape_results = scrape(scraper_args) # Very long function!
    return render(request, 'scrape_view.html', scrape_results )
```

This is a bad idea, as the `scrape` function takes a long time, and the user experience is terrible.

**My (probably bad) idea**

My idea was to:

- launch a celery task and render an intermediary view with the loading message and a "stop" button
- let the celery task store the scrape results somewhere (where?)
- find a way to revoke the task if the user presses the "stop" button
- retrieve the results of the celery task when the task is finished or when "stop" is being pressed
- cancel the scrape results after the page is closed, as I am simply interested in showing them on the website

As I am new to Django, I cannot evaluate if my idea is feasible or if it makes sense at all. Does anyone have a solution to propose, an alternative solution, or some examples to share? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with using celery, so celery will manage the queue of scraping tasks and execute them with a pool of workers, celery allows for you to store custom processing states see here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states

You will have and endpoint that will trigger a celery task execution to begin scraping. When a selenium scraping tasks begins celery will return a task ID which you can store and use for later reference.

Celery also allows the tasks to be revoked/cancelled by the celery task id see here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks , this will be your cancel button functionality.

In terms of updating the user via the website of the scraping progress, I would use celery in combination with django-channels and establish a web socket connection on your front end which will keep the scraping progress real time and avoid need for polling some rest endpoint: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @spy95 you can set `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', "db+postgresql://username:Password123@localhost/dbname")` which means all your celery task results will be in a postgres table which is easy to query in the future for other functionality

Comment: I have managed using the custom state as you suggested. Now the scrape task updates the state, and I store somewhere the task ID. With the ID I can read the state, get the results, and revoke the task whenever I want to.

I have used redis for the results backend (https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/redis.html)